# Mimikatz hash dump of logged-off users

Tags: passwords, hash

If I want to dump hashes of domain users on my computer, do they have to be logged on, or can I dump hashes of logged off users?

When I try mimikatz in my lab, I can only get dumps from others users if I switch accounts. But if I log out and run mimikatz, I only get dumps from local users and current logged-on domain user.